# Get a plural version of a string using EF's PluralizingTableNameConvention()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way I can get **exactly** the same plural output that Entity Framework's `PluralizingTableNameConvention` would do a table, just by passing in a string?

What I would like is something like:

```
public static string GetPluralised(string input) {
    Return ChangeToPluralizingTableNameConvention(input);
};
```

I can't find the base method that it uses. Additionally, if you could help point out how you found the method that PluralizingTableNameConvention  uses that would great for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can override customize PluralizingTableNameConvention as following :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

  modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<MyPluralizingTableNameConvention>();


  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public class MyPluralizingTableNameConvention : PluralizingTableNameConvention
{
  public override void Apply(EntityType item, DbModel model)
  {
    // Do your work here
    base.Apply(item, model);
  }
}
```

You can also inherte from `IConceptualModelConvention<EntityType>, IConvention` then you will have more flexibility by customing your convention.

Comment: Many thanks, I've edited my question to try and show you what I'm thinking. This is great info!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to import the reference `System.Data.Entity.Design`.

Then make sure you reference the namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices;
```

Then use something like:

```
    public static string ToPlural(this string s)
    {
        var ps = PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb"));
        return ps.Pluralize(s);
    }
```

Comment: so the problem is solved ^^ good job I just want to check it but it is done :-) +1 again 4 u